# Instrução jQuery só funciona pelo console

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, tenho duas instruções em jQuery que eu uso para:

- Marcar um checkbox
- Desabilitar uns radio buttons.

A questão é que essas instruções executada pelo sistema não funciona, mas se eu pegar a mesma e jogar no console do browser ocorre tudo corretamente

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: addressWebService+'auditoriaexcecao/getAuditorias/audi_id/'+audi_id,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(r){
    if(r.length >= 1){
        var hora;
        $.each(r, function(i, obj){

            hora = obj.auex_hora.split(":");
            hora[0] = hora[0] != '10' ? hora[0].replace("0", "") : hora[0];
            var processo = obj.auex_proc_id == 1 ? "smt" : "";

            /*Eu dei o console.log para ver oq estava sendo executado, se eu pegar o que printou no console, e executar por lá mesmo, funciona*/
            console.log("$(\".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']\").find(\"#tab"+hora[0]+processo+"\").find(\".check-ignorar-horario\").attr('checked', true);");
            console.log("$(\".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']\").find(\"#tab"+hora[0]+processo+"\").find(\".chck\").attr('disabled', 'disabled');");

            /*Estas são as duas instruções que não funcionam*/
            $(".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']").find("#tab"+hora[0]+processo).find(".check-ignorar-horario").attr('checked', true);
            $(".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']").find("#tab"+hora[0]+processo).find(".chck").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    }
});
```

Alguém consegue enxergar algum erro que eu não esteja vendo?

Comment: Talvez os elementos não existem no momento que tentam ser usados?

Comment: o pior que eles existem sim, esse meu ajax é uma função q eu só executo quando tudo já está carregado

Comment: @LucasCosta, talvez fosse isso mesmo, pq eu dei um setTimeout de 800mls e funcionou... MAs aí surge outra dúvida, esse ajax está dentro de uma função, que só é executada no .done de outro ajax... ele não teria que esperar concluir o primeiro para realizar o segundo?

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente a chamada das suas instruções está sendo efetuada antes dos elementos serem carregados.

Tente colocar o script pra ser carregado depois dos seus elementos.

Ou coloque sua função dentro dessa chamada:

```
     $(function(){
       //seu código aqui
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
$(function(){ 
$.ajax({
    url: addressWebService+'auditoriaexcecao/getAuditorias/audi_id/'+audi_id,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(r){
    if(r.length >= 1){
        var hora;
        $.each(r, function(i, obj){

            hora = obj.auex_hora.split(":");
            hora[0] = hora[0] != '10' ? hora[0].replace("0", "") : hora[0];
            var processo = obj.auex_proc_id == 1 ? "smt" : "";

            /*Eu dei o console.log para ver oq estava sendo executado, se eu pegar o que printou no console, e executar por lá mesmo, funciona*/
            console.log("$(\".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']\").find(\"#tab"+hora[0]+processo+"\").find(\".check-ignorar-horario\").attr('checked', true);");
            console.log("$(\".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']\").find(\"#tab"+hora[0]+processo+"\").find(\".chck\").attr('disabled', 'disabled');");

            /*Estas são as duas instruções que não funcionam*/
            $(".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']").find("#tab"+hora[0]+processo).find(".check-ignorar-horario").attr('checked', true);
            $(".div-pai[data-proc-id='"+obj.auex_proc_id+"']").find("#tab"+hora[0]+processo).find(".chck").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    }
}); 
});
```